# What is the recommended way to catch exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I have to do a code review and i got to a code part that addresses possibles exceptions. it looks to me that the developer coding works but i want to ask what is the usual and correct way to do that. What is the best way to do catch exceptions?
the coder wrote:

```
  try 
  { . . . }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (ex is PlatformNotSupportedException)
    { //for the Windows version or edition that does not support.
    // tracing
    }
    else if (ex is NotSupportedException || ex is IOException)
    { // for the NTFS not supported or EFS is not configured
      // tracing
    }
    else
    {
      //report any exception as encrypt/decrypt
    }
  }
```

I thought that *the book* says that it should be:

```
  catch (PlatformNotSupportedException pnse)
  {
    //for the Windows version or edition that does not support.
    // tracing
  }
  catch (NotSupportedException nse)
  {
    // for the NTFS not supported or EFS is not configured
    // tracing
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
    // tracing for IOE
  }   
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      //report any exception as encrypt/decrypt
  }
```

Comment: You are correct, although I see where they're coming from with the OR. That OR could probably be refactored as `catch (Exception e) when (e is NotSupportedException || e is IOException)`, and then the second option used.

Comment: @John the book probably pre-dates the addition of exception filters

Comment: @Marc Indeed, I think it was introduced in C# 6 if I remember correctly. I was more addressing why the developer who wrote the top code may have done it that way.

Answer (score 6):

The second approach would be more preferred. However, there is tiny difference between proposed solution and current one. You'd need to refactor to a method, or copy the code in two places (`NotSupportedException` and `IOException` catch blocks), whilst current implementation handles it under the same `if` block.

So, if you want to follow the same approach, you can use `when` [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) to filter out certain types and more.

```
  catch (PlatformNotSupportedException pnse)
  {
    // for the Windows version or edition that does not support.
    // tracing
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (ex is NotSupportedException || ex is IOException)
  {
    // for the NTFS not supported or EFS is not configured
    // tracing
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      //report any exception as encrypt/decrypt
  }
```

If that's not mandatory, you can leave implementation as is

Comment: I was working that into an answer myself, but I like your explanation better. :-)

Comment: I like this answer because it isn't all up tight about it. It ultimately comes down expressing the logic as clearly (and idiot-proof) as possible.

Comment: But *why* would the second approach be more preferred? As it stands, this answer is just expressing an opinion. (I mean, I do agree, but the answer needs to be justified.)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: **Use the second form so that the compiler catches ordering errors.**

The reason that you should use the second form is because then you will get a compile error if you attempt to handle the types in the wrong order.

For example, this will give you an actual compiler error:

```
try
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught 'Exception'");
}

// This gives a compile error:
// "Error CS0160  A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type ('Exception')"

catch (SystemException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught 'SystemException'");
}
```

However, using `if/else if` will NOT cause a compile error, so the error goes unnoticed:

```
try
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught 'Exception'");
    }
    else if (ex is SystemException) // This will never be reached, but no compile error.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught 'SystemException'");
    }
}
```

Note, however, that tools such as Resharper will warn you for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

this would be generic for all type of exception

```
try 
{
   .....code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: in this case it  looks like there are exception-specific things to do, so...